# Failed to create comet support class in JBoss 6.4

Tags: jboss, comet, jboss6.x

> Error: failed to create comet support class: class org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport, error: null

When I try to start JBoss with my application this error occurs; without my application the server starts fine. POM editor says atmosphere 2.42 is a dependency, which is the comet dependency I think.

How do I resolve comet dependency so JBoss is able to resolve it (STFW)?

Comment: See https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Enabling-WebSocket-Support-in-JBoss-EAP-6.3-and-up